# 100vh does not fill all the content placed in its tag

Tags: html, css

I'm new to technology in general, which brings me some doubts, when I was studying a bit of CSS, I realized that when I add 100vh to my #container if it has a lot of content it ends up "jumping" out of its square and wanted to know why.

[problem in pag html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5AuN.png)

[section in css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W19gi.png)

in short because when I add the 100vh to my container it ends up not filling all the content

```css
body {
  background-color: #878787;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 60px 0 60px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Glossário</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
    <h2>Termos de descrição</h2>
    <dl>
      <dt>The Description List</dt>
      <dd>Uma lista de pares de termos e descrições</dd>
      <dt>The Description Term </dt>
      <dd>Identifica um termo na lista de definição</dd>
      <dt>The Description Details</dt>
      <dd>Fornece detalhes ou uma definição mais completa do termo</dd>
      <dt>Lorem ipsum</dt>
      <dd>dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</dd><dt>The Description List</dt>
      <dd>Uma lista de pares de termos e descrições</dd>
      <dt>The Description Term </dt>
      <dd>Identifica um termo na lista de definição</dd>
      <dt>The Description Details</dt>
      <dd>Fornece detalhes ou uma definição mais completa do termo</dd>
      <dt>Lorem ipsum</dt>
      <dd>dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</dd><dt>The Description List</dt>
      <dd>Uma lista de pares de termos e descrições</dd>
      <dt>The Description Term </dt>
      <dd>Identifica um termo na lista de definição</dd>
      <dt>The Description Details</dt>
      <dd>Fornece detalhes ou uma definição mais completa do termo</dd>
      <dt>Lorem ipsum</dt>
      <dd>dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</dd>
    </dl>

  </main>
</div>
<footer>
  <span>Synxther</span>
</footer>
```

Comment: Why use 100vh at all?

Comment: It might be worthwhile reading through the [MDN CSS units page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units), `vh` units are relative to the viewport, and are probably not appropriate for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving your container a fixed height of `100vh` so when the content inside of it is bigger, it will not fit. If what you want to do is make sure your container is atleast `100vh` but grow as your content gets bigger, replace `height: 100vh` with `min-height: 100vh`.

Answer (score 0):

100vh equals to height of your viewport, i.e. browser window. I has nothing to do with your content. You should use 100% instead, or just remove height at all, since it is 100% by default